SwiftUI: How to make .draggable() respond immediately without delay?
In my SwiftUI application, the drag and drop feature is a core functionality, especially on one specific screen where it's used frequently.
By default, there's a small delay before the drag starts (a long press), but I would like the user to be able to grab and move an item immediately without waiting. Is there a simple way to make .draggable() respond instantly, without requiring a long press?
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated! I’d prefer to avoid re-implementing the whole feature with DragGesture, as my app is already set up with .draggable().
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:
Setting allowHitTesting to false — Drag and drop doesn't work at all.
Tried running in both normal and debug modes — Same behavior persists.
Enabled EditMode — Same behavior persists.
Text(s)
    .padding()
    .background(.red)
    .draggable(s)


The default behavior of .draggable() sometimes involves a delay, especially on mobile devices where it expects a long-press gesture before starting. To make it respond instantly, you can use a simultaneous gesture that triggers a drag right away.
you can use the DragGesture and combine it with .gesture() for instant drag responses.
    struct InstantDraggableView: View {
    @State private var offset: CGSize = .zero  // To track the position
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Drag Me")
            .padding()
            .background(Color.blue)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .offset(offset)  // Update position based on drag
            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { gesture in
                        offset = gesture.translation  // Update offset as user drags
                    }
                    .onEnded { _ in
                        // Optional: Add logic if you want to reset or constrain the drag
                        }
                )
        }
    }
    struct InstantDraggableView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        InstantDraggableView()
    }
}

Instead of relying on .draggable() (which has built-in delays), using DragGesture() gives you full control over the dragging behavior.
If you need to combine this with other gestures (like tap or long-press), you can use .simultaneousGesture().

Yeah i know for this way. I assume that's the only way..
